# Creating links for all letters of the alphabet

Tags: javascript, php

I want to put the alphabet on top of a page. When someone clicks on a letter, a small json file containing words starting with that letter is loaded.

How do I simply create those letters with seperate id's on the top of my page, without manually typing all 26 of them?

I've [found this](http://www.primitivetype.com/articles/create_alphabet_links_with_php.php) code in PHP which does almost exactly what I want to achieve:

```
for ($i = 65; $i <= 90; $i++) {
    printf('<a href="%1$s.html" class="myclass">%1$s</a> ', chr($i));
}
```

How would one do this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript use [fromCharCode](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```
var html = '', chr = '';
for (var i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    chr = String.fromCharCode(i);
    html+= '<a href="'+ chr +'.html" class="myclass">'+ chr +'</a> ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in JavaScript like so...

```
var startOffset = "a".charCodeAt(0);
var letterIndex;
var letter;
var letterAnchor;

for (letterIndex = startOffset; letterIndex < startOffset + 26; letterIndex++) {
    letter = String.fromCharCode(letterIndex);
    letterA = document.createElement("a");
    letterA.textContent = letter;
    letterA.href = letter + ".html";
    document.body.appendChild(letterA);
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to generate HTML, then replace the body of the `for` loop with something like...

```
html += letter.link(letter + ".html");
```

Personally, I'd place each one of these links into items of an ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var a = "A".charCodeAt(0); i < "Z".charCodeAt(0); i++) {
    html += "<a href='" + a + ".html'>" + a + "</a>"
}
```